# Comparing boolean values

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-logic

I am facing an issue while comparing boolean values, I want the loop to enter inside the block but its not entering the block.

```
else if (!(keyCompare.contains(compareKey)) || (save == true)) {
 //do something
}
```

here `!(keyCompare.contains(compareKey)` will return false. I am seeing if the vector keyCompare does not have compareKey or if save is true then enter if loop, but its not.

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any errors here, there must be something else. If save is true, it will enter your if-block. Btw, don't write `if (save == true)`, just write `if(save)`

Comment: what is your first if condition? Are you sure it's not entering the previous branch?

Comment: Could you please show the whole `if-else` statement

Comment: More readable: `else if (!keyCompare.contains(compareKey) || save) {`

Comment: An if is not a loop. Post more of your code so that someone can try and help you out.

Comment: just a note, `contains()` requires `equals()` method implemented correctly, so if compareKey is instance of object you created, that could be the problem...

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities:

1. An if or else if block above this one is executing.
2. An exception is being thrown by contains.
3. You're incorrect and both of those conditions are false.

A debugger will tell you exactly which possibility is correct.  There's not really any need for discussion here - those are literally the only three possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a class as follows:

```
static class Contents {
  private String contents;
  public Contents(String contents) {
    this.contents = contents;
  }
}
```

Writing the following code:

```
Vector<Contents> v = new Vector<>();
v.add(new Contents("a"));
System.out.println("Contains a: "+v.contains(new Contents("a")));
```

Would yield the following output:

```
Contains a: false
```

However adding the `equals` method to the `Contents` class as follows:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  return Objects.equals(this.contents, ((Contents)obj).contents);
}
```

Yields suddenly the following result:

```
Contains a: true
```

A better implementation might have looked as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (this == obj) return true;
  if (obj == null) return false;
  if (getClass() != obj.getClass())return false;
  final Contents other = (Contents) obj;
  if (!Objects.equals(this.contents, other.contents))return false;
  return true;
}
```